# IBM Worklight: downloading and replacing resources from webview

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

What I want to do is displaying a website (a Portal one) within Worklight. So I'm hardcoding the URL in the `mainFile` tag:

```
<mainFile>http://example.com/page.html</mainFile>
```

Now I need to download the resources from this page *(JS and CSS files)*, store them locally and replace the absolute URLs of the page with WorkLight URLs in order to speed up the page loading.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the `mainFile` (the "index.html") value during runtime, as it is set in application-descriptor.xml which is a server-side file that the build process uses.

I would also question the flow. If you want to speed up application loading, hinting that by using Portal the loading is slow, why use Portal to begin with? Place your resources locally in the application.

Comment: No problem. Worklight has a Direct Update feature to update the web resources.

Comment: But how can I tell Worklight to use local resources instead of remote ones once the remote mainFile has been displayed?

Comment: You can't. I'm saying that you should use only local resources. That is, not use Portal because what you're asking for is not possible to mix together.